# Splitting strings from integers in R

Tags: r, statistics

I've recently come across an interesting problem while trying to
create a custom database.

my rows are in form:

```
 183746IGH
 105928759UBS
```

and so on (so basically an integer concatenated with a string, both of relatively random sizes.). What I'm trying to do is somehow separate the whole number in column 1 and everything else(the letters) in column 2. How can this be done? I've been trying with strsplit but it doesn't seem to offer this kind of functionality.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I dont know r, but for other languages (C, Java...) you could get the position of the first letter (if character >ascii code 39Hex, the number 9). if you cant do that, you can get each character one by one and check if it is a number or a letter

Comment: If these are identifiers of some kind, my advice is, don't try to separate the bits but rather just use them whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("adad131341", "adadar45365", "cavsbsb425", "daadvsv46567567"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(V2 = str_extract(V1, "[0-9]+"),
              V3 = str_extract(V1, "[aA-zZ]+"))
```

Which gives:

```
#               V1       V2      V3
#1      adad131341   131341    adad
#2     adadar45365    45365  adadar
#3      cavsbsb425      425 cavsbsb
#4 daadvsv46567567 46567567 daadvsv
```

Answer (score 6):

Other options include `tstrsplit` from the devel version of `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[,tstrsplit(V1,'(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)', perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
#        V1      V2
#1:   131341    adad
#2:    45365  adadar
#3:      425 cavsbsb
#4: 46567567 daadvsv
```

If there are elements were 'non-numeric' part appears first and 'numeric' last, then, we can use a bit more generalized option as the regex pattern,

```
 setDT(df)[,tstrsplit(V1, "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)",
                  perl = TRUE)]
```

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, V1, into=c('V1', 'V2'), '(\\d+)(\\D+)', convert=TRUE)
#        V1      V2
#1   131341    adad
#2    45365  adadar
#3      425 cavsbsb
#4 46567567 daadvsv
```

If you need the original column as well,

```
 extract(df, V1, into=c('V2', 'V3'), '(\\d+)(\\D+)',
                               convert=TRUE, remove=FALSE)
 #               V1       V2      V3
 #1      131341adad   131341    adad
 #2     45365adadar    45365  adadar
 #3      425cavsbsb      425 cavsbsb
 #4 46567567daadvsv 46567567 daadvsv
```

For the `data.table`, we can use `:=` to create the new columns so that the existing columns remain in the output, i.e.

```
setDT(df)[,paste0('V',2:3):=tstrsplit(V1,'(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)',
                     perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
#               V1       V2      V3
#1:      131341adad   131341    adad
#2:     45365adadar    45365  adadar
#3:      425cavsbsb      425 cavsbsb
#4: 46567567daadvsv 46567567 daadvsv
```

NOTE: Both the solutions have the option to convert the class of the split columns (`type.convert/convert`).

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("131341adad", "45365adadar", "425cavsbsb", 
               "46567567daadvsv"))
```

Comment: I didn't see this when I came here. This is more compact than my answer. +1

Answer (score 5):

And another way with base-R and regular expressions:

```
all <- c(' 183746IGH','105928759UBS')

numeric <- sapply(a, function(x) sub('[[:alpha:]]+','', x))

alphabetic <- sapply(a, function(x) sub('[[:digit:]]+','', x))

    > data.frame(all,alphabetic,numeric)
                      all alphabetic   numeric
 183746IGH      183746IGH        IGH    183746
105928759UBS 105928759UBS        UBS 105928759
```

Or as per @rawr's comment below:

```
> read.table(text = gsub('(\\d)(\\D)', '\\1 \\2', all))
         V1  V2
1    183746 IGH
2 105928759 UBS
```

Or a vectorised version of the above with a function:

```
get_alphanum <- function(x, type) {
  type <- switch(type,
                 alpha = '[[:digit:]]+',
                 digit = '[[:alpha:]]+')
  sub(type,'', x)
}

get_alphanum <- Vectorize(get_alphanum)
```

Which gives a result applied directly on a vector!

```
> get_alphanum(all, type='alpha')
   183746IGH 105928759UBS 
      " IGH"        "UBS" 
> get_alphanum(all, type='digit')
   183746IGH 105928759UBS 
   " 183746"  "105928759"
```

which can also be used to create a data.frame:

```
> data.frame(all, 
             alpha=get_alphanum(all, type='alpha') ,
             numeric=get_alphanum(all, type='digit'))
                      all alpha   numeric
 183746IGH      183746IGH   IGH    183746
105928759UBS 105928759UBS   UBS 105928759
```

Comment: @rawr Thanks for this. I just went into a coding frenzy above :P and produced an overkill. I have added in my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I've been known to do that as well

Answer (score 4):

`strsplit` does work if you provide the correct regex to split on.

In this case, you would want something like:

```
strsplit(String, split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)
```

Here it is applied to @Steven's sample data:

```
strsplit(as.character(df$V1), split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "adad"   "131341"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "adadar" "45365" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "cavsbsb" "425"    
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "daadvsv"  "46567567"
```

Some time in the past I've written a function to do this since my mind honestly doesn't think in regex very often. The function looks like:

```
SplitMe <- function(string, alphaFirst = TRUE, bind = FALSE) {
  if (!is.character(string)) string <- as.character(string)
  Pattern <- ifelse(isTRUE(alphaFirst),
                    "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", 
                    "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])")
  out <- strsplit(string, split = Pattern, perl = TRUE)
  if (isTRUE(bind)) {
    require(data.table)
    as.data.table(do.call(rbind, out))
  } else {
    out
  } 
}
```

The intended usage was something like:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, c("char", "num") := SplitMe(V1, bind = TRUE)][]
#                 V1    char      num
# 1:      adad131341    adad   131341
# 2:     adadar45365  adadar    45365
# 3:      cavsbsb425 cavsbsb      425
# 4: daadvsv46567567 daadvsv 46567567
```

---

Once you know that pattern, you can use it in other places that make use of `strsplit`, like `separate` from "tidyr", which conveniently separates values into columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("char", "num"), 
           sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)
#      char      num
# 1    adad   131341
# 2  adadar    45365
# 3 cavsbsb      425
# 4 daadvsv 46567567
```

Comment: @akrun, but the concept can be generalized from it. I don't feel that we are here to answer a single person's question. Rather, we are trying to offer more generalized solutions that others can benefit from.

Comment: Yes, if the OP is not wellversed in regex, the code may not split in the correct way.  When I posted the solution, I was using steven's dataset, but then I changed it, but you are correct that it can be generalized.

Comment: For example, `"(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"` is one option

Comment: @akrun, see! That's the awesome thinking that comes out when you aren't trying to solve one person's problem. I like that! Now I need to change my `SplitMe` function :-)

Answer (score 3):

`read.pattern` in the gsubfn package can do that.  Each parenthesized part of the regular expression given in the `pattern` argument will be read into a separate column:

```
x <- c("183746IGH", "105928759UBS")

library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = x, pattern = "(\\d+)(\\D+)")
```

giving:

```
         V1  V2
1    183746 IGH
2 105928759 UBS
```